# Drupal and Exchange Server Calendar

Tags: drupal, calendar, exchange-server

Is there a module, or other way to integrate Drupal/Drupal Calendar and Exchange Server Calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If your calendar server has an exposed web service, you can use XMLRPC / Services module to retrieve data and save it to your Drupal application.

Drupal can be instructed to grab data from a web service and bring it back in an HTTP response. From there you can run the data through a function to save the data into a node.

Comment: Thank you for your response,
Do you know where I can find a detailed guide on doing this?

Comment: By the way, is it possible to turn it the other way around... like i want to export data from my drupal event calendar to exchange server calendar, so that i want to sync my outlook with the exchange server and maintain same events in both of them.

Comment: @samJL Unfortunately you won't find such guide, you must figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

If your calendar server exposes .ical feeds, you can use CCK, FeedAPI, and Feed Element Mapper to import the data as Drupal content.  This provides one way synchronization.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please... do u mean exchange server exposes .ical feeds, and we need to import them into our drupal? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes.  Exchange would expose the feeds and Drupal would import events as nodes for display.  Here's a video that demonstrates what I mean: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode34